# Does Anchor support const generics?

Tags: anchor

I have a struct I'm defining like below:

```
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct MyStruct<const MY_CONST: usize> {
    vals: [u32; MY_CONST],
}
```

When I try to `anchor build` this, I get

```
thread 'main' panicked at lang/syn/src/idl/parse/mod.rs:17:76:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }
```

I believe the const generic is what's causing the problem here since if I change it to

```
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    vals: [u32; 100],
}
```

it builds fine. Therefore my question is does Anchor support const generics and, if yes, how do I fix the error I'm encountering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking the Anchor Github, I came across this issue with the same problem: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/632

At the bottom of the thread, one of the maintainers answers that this is fixed by this PR: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/2824 , which is from 3 weeks ago.

Therefore the answer to my question is Anchor does not support const generics, but will in v0.30.0.

Comment: Looks like 0.30.0 will have many great features :) I hope it will come soon.